# Improve Regex to match font files in css files

Tags: javascript, php, regex, fonts, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match font files that are contained in CSS files.
The font files can have the following extensions : 
And following format :

```
- url("../../../../fonts/font_awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3")
- url("../../../../fonts/font_awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular")
```

In this case the match should be :

```
../../../../fonts/font_awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3
../../../../fonts/font_awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular
```

I have already made a regex that matches them successfully, however on using an online service, the regex returned to me a warning saying that it has a catastrophic backtracking, so I'm asking how can this Regex be better :

```
url\s*\(\s*\S(.+?\.(woff|eot|woff2|ttf|svg)\s*)\??\S+?\s?\)
```

Regex in action with the backtracking warning : https://regex101.com/r/KWsh1X/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

`url\("([^\)]+?\.(woff|eot|woff2|ttf|svg)[^"]*)"`

Here you can play around: https://regex101.com/r/KWsh1X/2

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for the suggestion, however it's not always the case being fontawesome, it can be different, any suggestions?

Comment: Great answer, have compared it with the other answers, this is the one that finds matches in less steps !

Answer (score 1):

Look like it's late but maybe will be helpfull too

```
url\(['"]([^"']+(woff|eot|woff2|ttf|svg)[^"']+)
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed finds all the matches, however with 600-700 more steps than Martin's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
\W+url\W+"([^"]+\.(woff|eot|woff2|ttf|svg)[^"]+)"\W+
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed finds all the matches, however in a lot of steps, that's why not voted as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do as many steps if you don't include the file formats.

```
/url\("(.*?)"\)/
```